# Paso de parámetros por la URL de array indexado, que contiene arrays asociativos con PHP

Tags: php, array, url

Tengo un grupo de cards en una vista, y deseo que al hacer click sobre alguna de ellas se abra otra pagina destino denominada project-show donde indico los detalles del proyecto de interés. Debo indicar que cuando hago click, por ejemplo sobre una de las cards cuyo `project_id=pp0000001`, en la URL me aparece lo siguiente `localhost/myweb/project-show?project_id=pp0000001`. Y cuando voy a la página destino me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> Notice: Undefinied index project_id en C:\wamp\www\myweb\views\project-show.php in line 3

En la pagina destino `project-show.php` tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
  $project_controller = new ProjectController();
  $project = $project_controller->get($_GET["project_id"]);
```

Y en la página origen:

```
<?php
    $project_controller = new ProjectController();
    $project = $project_controller->get();

    $template_project = '<div class="cards">';

    for ($n = 0; $n < count($project); $n++) {

      $template_project .= '

  <a href="project-show?project_id=' . $project[$n]['project_id'] . '" class="card"
   data-category="' . $project[$n]['category'] . '" >
    <div class="card-poster">
      <img src="' . $project[$n]['poster'] . '" alt="' . $project[$n]['poster'] . '" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <div class="project_id">
        <p>Project.id: <span>' . $project[$n]['project_id'] . '</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        <p>Inicio :<span class="initiation-date">' . $project[$n]['initiation'] . '</span></p>
        <p>Fin :<span class="finalitation-date">' . $project[$n]['finish'] . '</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="summary">
        <h2 class="title_project">' . $project[$n]['title'] . '</h2>
        <div class="others">
          <p class="director">Director:<span>' . $project[$n]['director'] . '</span></p>
          <img src="' . $project[$n]['flag'] . '" alt="' . $project[$n]['flag'] . '">
        </div>
        <p class="plot">' . $project[$n]['plot1'] . '</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-progress">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="percent">
          <svg>
            <circle cx="65" cy="50" r="30" class="track"></circle>
            <circle cx="65" cy="50" r="30" class="progress"></circle>
          </svg>
          <div class="number">
            <h6>' . $project[$n]['progress'] . '<span>%</span></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="objetive">
          <p>Objetivo:</p>
          <span>' . $project[$n]['objetive'] . ' ikhor' . '</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-stats">
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">4 <sup>m</sup></div>
        <div class="type">read</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat border">
        <div class="value">5123</div>
        <div class="type">views</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stat">
        <div class="value">32</div>
        <div class="type">comments</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ';
    }
       $template_project .= '
                </div>
              </article>
           </section>
        </main>
        ';

     print($template_project);
```

Les indico que en la vista donde aparecen todas las 12 cards, está todo perfecto.. me cargan las imágenes y todos los campos establecidos en la base de datos, que coloco en cada card.. Los cuales listo: project_id, title, plot1, director, responsible, country, initiation, finish, flag, poster, progress, objetive.

Cuando ejecuto `var_dump($project)` en la página destino , me aparecen todos los campos con sus nombres y valores, de las 12 cards que tengo en mi base de datos.. Cuando debe ser solo la que clickeo...

Bueno, en realidad lo que me interesa es poder recuperar en la página destino el *project_id* de cada project, y luego en la página destino utilizar ese campo para invocar un método `get()` que me invoque los otros campos...

Realizando varias consultas, entendí que el array $project no es un array asociativo, este en realidad es un array indexado que contiene arrays asociativos..

Muchas gracias a los amigos Stack Overflow por su asistencia.

Comment: cuando haces submit de datos en un form se envia todo; no una seccion a menos que lo controles mediante javascript.

Comment: para tener mas datos de que y como se estan reciviendo los datos intenta hacer un `var_dump($_GET)` esto se usa para saber que recibes...

Comment: ¿Esto es un duplicado? [Paso de parámetros por la URL con PHP de array asociativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412607/paso-de-par%c3%a1metros-por-la-url-con-php-de-array-asociativo)

Comment: SI.. amigo.. pero en la anterior no estaba todo el codigo..

Comment: @LuisMonagas debiste editar la original ... para eso esta la opción de editar... te sugiero que Elimines las preguntas antes que comiences a recibir votos negativos...

Comment: Ahhh ok.. Gracias.. Lo haré

Comment: Listo.. Eliminada las otras preguntas

Comment: Buenos día Francisco Núñez, cuando hago click sobre la card de interés (la cual no es un formulario), requiero que solo se pase por la url el parámetro project_Id, la verdad, lo logre, y hasta se puede observar por al url el parámetro enviado.. Lo único es que no puedo recuperarlo con $_GET.. y cuando utilizo var_dump, me indica que el valor es null.. Será como usted me indica, que se requiere utilizar algún módulo de javascript para decodificar lo enviado por la url y el método $_GET lo pueda leer.. Muchas gracias.. buscaré la manera que usted me aconseja. Saludos desde Venezuela (08/12/2020)